# Convert string date to mysql date in php

Tags: php, date

Trying to convert this date format 'Fri Aug 28 05:07:13 CEST 2020' to 'H-m-s m-d-Y' format using :

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", strtotime($this->s($entry["'FIRST_TIMESTAMP'"])))
```

It doesn't work; do i need to manually parse it or is there a better way of doing it.

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat` takes a *string* and parses it into a `DateTime` object. `strtotime` takes a *string* and parses it and returns an integer… I hope it's somewhat obvious how those two don't really go together…?

Answer (score 3):

Create a new DateTime object with your string as constructor argument. PHP will automatically parse the date time string.

Then call format method to format it to required format.

```php
php > $dt = new DateTime("Fri Aug 28 05:07:13 CEST 2020");
php > echo $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
2020-08-28 05:07:13
php > echo $dt->format("H-m-s m-d-Y");
05-08-13 08-28-2020
```

Please do note that "H-m-s m-d-Y" doesn't make any sense: it will output hour-month-second month-day-year

The correct format should be "H-i-s m-d-Y": hour-minute-second month-day-year

```
php > echo $dt->format("H-i-s m-d-Y");
05-07-13 08-28-2020
```

Comment: Brilliant and yes it was a typo from me :)